# Is there an easy way to combine multiple fold methods?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding

I like folding a lot. I like code syntax based folding, custom marker based folding, folding multi line comments, folding parentheses, folding braces, and probably other things I am forgetting. To accomplish this I write custom syntax files and use the syntax fold method, which I hate a lot. Is there a better way?

As a specific example, I am not aware of any way to combine code syntax folding (like C style folding) and custom marker based folding ({{{ }}}) other than to write a custom syntax file. I really like using custom marker folds to keep things organized.

My problem with using the syntax method with custom syntax files is that I find them incredibly finicky and frustrating. If there exists a repository of existing syntax files that include various alternate folding rules I would find that useful.

My ideal solution would be to be able to specify a list of independent folding "situations" that are efficiently computed and don't mess up the existing syntax and which don't require me to write syntax rules.

Comment: Welcome to vim :-) Your question is somehow vague. Could you share with us the downside of your method? In particular how the buildin syntaxes do not fit your need?

Comment: You are probably right, in the sense that I am not convinced that there does exist a better method. But I find that I am repeatedly wrong about such things.